# Can't update a laravel model visible attribute

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent

I have a simple form and a function to update my products. As this is not the only place where I will need to update products, I decided to move the function inside the model itself, so I can reuse it later:

```
class Producto extends Model
{
    public function update($vales){

        $this -> disponible = $values['disponible'];
        $this -> tipo = $values['tipo'];
        $this -> marca = $values['marca'];
        $this -> visible = $values['visible'];
        $this -> upc = $values['upc'];

        $this -> save();

        return;
    }
}
```

Is it correct to update the model using $this? I tested it and it works and updates everything, except for the column called "visible". I tried to find what is wrong but everything seems to be just ok, and it looks like it just doesn't want to update that specific column.

I tried changing that line for testing purposes to:

```
$this -> visible = "some hardcoded value";
```

But it's still somehow not working... I tried updating the model from the controller using:

```
$product -> visible = $values['visible'];
```

And it works as expected, but the point of putting that function into the model is to make it reusable. Everything in the database looks ok, and this is driving me crazy. So the only thing that could be the problem as I can see is having to use $this to update the model, but I'm not sure if that is correct or not.

Comment: Define "somehow not working". What happens?

Comment: Your code is correct something else is going on, what type is visible?

Comment: Did you added `visible` on your **Producto** model's fillable property?

Comment: Well, the value of "visible" is not updating in the database, it stays the same. It is varchar as the other columns, but that is the only one that is not updating!. I moved the exactly same code to the controller, changing "$this" to "$product" referencing the model and it works, but not when the function is in the model

Comment: Yes, I tried adding visible in the fillable property, but that did not help. I also tried with protected $guarded = [];

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Larvel model has defined attribute called hidden and visible on the class.
[Documentation](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/eloquent-serialization#hiding-attributes-from-json)

Either dont use that name as a table field in your database (think about using field name `is_visible`)

**Or** use this code to update that field.

```php
$this->setAttribute('visible', $values['visible']);
```

It [will not bypass mutator](https://github.com/laravel/framework/blob/5.8/src/Illuminate/Database/Eloquent/Concerns/HasAttributes.php#L563) if you have one in place.

What it will do is specificly change the field present in the attribute (array) `attributes` wich contain the value you recovered from DB.

```
$this->attributes[$key] = $value;
```

You can also use this last one, but it will bypass mutators